# Brownie cannot get networks via alchemy in project brownie-config.yaml

Tags: python, solidity, config, brownie

Context:

- Win10
- Brownie v1.20.2

Explanation:

Since `network` field is deprecated in the brownie-config.yaml, it's possible to use `networks` directly instead, which can be successfully checked with `brownie console` invoking `config` dict and check that the nets are properly gathered.

The problem is that, when invoking that network, it looks up in the built-in brownie-config instead of the project one.

Reproduction of the problem:

brownie-config.yaml file:

```yaml
dependencies:
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0

compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0'

dotenv: .env

wallets:
  from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}

networks:
  # any settings given here will replace the defaults
  development:
    host: http://127.0.0.1
    gas_price: 0
    persist: false
    reverting_tx_gas_limit: 6721975
    test_rpc:
      cmd: ganache-cli
      port: 8545
      gas_limit: 6721975
      accounts: 10
      evm_version: istanbul
      mnemonic: brownie
  # set your Infura API token to the environment variable WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID
  mainnet:
    host: https://polygon-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/${ALCHEMY_MAINNET_AK}
  sepolia:
    host: https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/${ALCHEMY_SEPOLIA_AK}
  polygon:
    host: https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/${ALCHEMY_MAINPOLYGON_AK}
```

dependencies are successfully gathered from the project brownie-config.yaml. However,

`$brownie run .\scripts\2_deploy_ez_token.py --network sepolia`
`>>> ValueError: Unable to expand environment variable in host setting: 'https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/$WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID'`

so it's ignoring the part of `networks` in the project brownie-config. However if checking the `config` dict,

`$brownie console`
`config`

```
...
   
        },
        'live': {
            'default_contract_owner': False,
            'gas_buffer': 1.1,
            'gas_limit': "auto",
            'gas_price': None,
            'max_fee': None,
            'priority_fee': "auto",
            'reverting_tx_gas_limit': False
        },
        'mainnet': {
            'host': "https://polygon-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/dFChI7q5-QpOzf6oY6grd--wqPaiggMT"
        },
        'polygon': {
            'host': "https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/vaUCnwgp0yj6Y94KLIqrpJwCVdVK2yl5"
        },
        'sepolia': {
            'host': "https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/Ft6IARQMkXZujCVJ9V4qEOvVhVw0XfJK"
        }
    },
    'project_structure': {
...
```

so clearly the `config` dict variable is right. So.. how to successfully make that brownie-config.yaml get the project network info with alchemist? Any suggestion? Thanks. Regards.

Comment: I've just realized that "Brownie is no longer actively maintained".

Source: https://pypi.org/project/eth-brownie/

So, alternative is Hardhat in javascript.